# Please install sqlite3 package manually after electron-packager on linux for windows

Tags: node.js, sqlite, electron, electron-packager

I am trying to package my app with electron-packager. My app have as dependencies sqlite3 and sequelize.

here is my package.json file :

```
{
  "name": "electronjs_base",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Projet de base Electron JS",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron main.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "postinstall": "install-app-deps",
    "rebuild": "electron-rebuild -f -w sqlite3"
  },
  "author": "Aurélien Colombet & Steven Servanton",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^4.0.3",
    "electron-builder": "^20.38.5",
    "electron-packager": "^13.0.1",
    "electron-rebuild": "^1.8.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "ejs": "^2.6.1",
    "electron-reload": "^1.4.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "formidable": "^1.2.1",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "sequelize": "^4.42.0",
    "sqlite3": "^4.0.6"
  }
}
```

I am on linux and I am trying to build my app for windows. I use `electron-packager` for that, with that command :

```
electron-packager . gamemaster_interface --overwrite --platform=win32 --arch=x64 --out=release-builds
```

My app works well on linux when I launch it with `npm run start`, but when I am trying to run it on windows with the executable file created by electron-packager I have a javascript error :

[image: Exception raise when launching windows executable]

I don't know how to solve that problem, I have trying multiple things like adding sqlite3 in devDependencies instead of dependencies in the package.json but I still have the error.

Thank you for reading me and I hope someone have the solution :).

Have a nice day !

Comment: I have also faced same issue.I downloaded sqlite3 node module on a windows machine and then re-builded it on the same machine. Then I used this node module to package the application.

Comment: Finally we made the ".exe" file from windows machine itself. Some node modules builded on one operating system might not work on other. You can ping me for any help.

Comment: Yes thanks for the answer, but I want to make it work because I will install that application on multiple machine and I don't want to rebuild my app every time I will install an app :/.

Comment: I build my app on windows and when I execute the .exe from another computer with windows it works. So the solution is to build the app on a windows computer. But I am still curious to know if it is possible to make it works on linux :).